# Java MySQL NullPointerException on query

Tags: java, sql, nullpointerexception

Basically I have a problem with getting a ResultSet from a database. The errors occur around Line 34 (?) in this code block but I've marked it

```
ResultSet rs = caq.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ProjectScore"); //error goes here
```

I get a null pointer exception on runtime and this is the output from the catch statement below:

```
null, calculating average score failed

java.lang.NullPointerException

[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1de2b1
```

The interesting thing is that I use the Connection Exactly the same in the class at the end and I receive no errors there. Copying the statement to the first class doesn't work either so I assume it's something else. I think that's all I have, any help is appreciated :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //.......................
    private int [] averageScore;

    //References
    private LogInWindow liw;
    private NewUserWindow nuw;
    private ScoreWindow sw;
    private boolean isAnotherWindowOpen = false;
    private boolean isLoggedIn = false;
    private ConnectionAndQueries caq;

    public MainWindow(ConnectionAndQueries caq) throws SQLException{
        this.caq = caq;

        //.................................

        //Middle
        averageScore = new int [9];
        calculateAverageScore();
        setTable();

        //............................
    }

    private void calculateAverageScore() throws SQLException{
        try{
            ResultSet rs = caq.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ProjectScore"); //error goes here
            int [] count = new int [9];
            int [] totalScore = new int [9];

            while(rs.next()){
                int itemID = rs.getInt("itemID");

                count[itemID]++;
                totalScore[itemID] += rs.getInt("Score");
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                averageScore[i] = totalScore[i] / count[i];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(", calculating average score failed");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }
}




//next class

import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionAndQueries {
    private static Connection connection;
    private static Statement statement;
    private MainWindow mw;

    public ConnectionAndQueries() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        mw = new MainWindow(this);
        connect();
    }

    public static void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://zzzzzzzzzz", "yyyy",     "xxxx"); //dont think im allowed to give that info
            statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connecting to the database failed");
        }
    }

    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
        return statement.executeQuery(query);
    }

    public int executeUpdate(String update) throws SQLException {
          return statement.executeUpdate(update);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        ConnectionAndQueries caq = new ConnectionAndQueries();
    }
}




//another class which uses the connection class, and works.

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LogInWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //........................

    //References
    private MainWindow mw;
    private ConnectionAndQueries caq;

    public LogInWindow(MainWindow mw, ConnectionAndQueries caq){
        this.mw = mw;
        this.caq = caq;

        //......................
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == logIn){
            String usn = usernameField.getText();
            String pwd = passwordField.getText();

            try {
                ResultSet rs = caq.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ProjectCustomer");

                while(rs.next()){
                    if(rs.getString("username").equals(usn)){
                        if(rs.getString("passwrd").equals(pwd)){
                            logInSuccess(usn);
                            mw.userLoggedIn(usn);
                            quit();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(mw.isUserLoggedIn() == false)
                    logInFailed();

            } catch (Exception e2) {
                System.out.print(e2.getMessage());
                System.out.println(", error at log in");
                System.out.println(e2.toString());
            }
        }

        else if(e.getSource() == quit){
            quit();
        }
    }

    //............................
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this constructor is called, it sends a reference of itself to MainWindow.

```
public ConnectionAndQueries() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    mw = new MainWindow(this);
    connect();
}
```

However, as this reference is sent while the object being referenced has not yet been constructed (that is, the constructor has not yet finished) the reference can only be null at this point.

One way to monkey-fix this would be move the code from the constructor to the main method, below *new ConnectionAndQueries()*. However, I strongly recommend refactoring the program structure to separate the database connections and operations into one or more separate classes, as well as decoupling the UI code from the database code.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, sadly I can't do all those fixes because I'm not allowed to change program structure :(

Answer (score 2):

Problem is because of the constructor.

> public ConnectionAndQueries() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
>
> > mw = new MainWindow(this);
> >
> > > connect();
> > >
> > > > }

Here from the constructor of Mainwindow, its makding call to calculateAverageScore, which is executing a query with the ConnectionAndQueries. As connect() is not called so far, connection and statement is null. And so getting null pointer exception.

Try, calling connect() before mw = new MainWindow(this); statement.

> public ConnectionAndQueries() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
>
> > connect();
> >
> > > mw = new MainWindow(this);
> > >
> > > > }

But for sure code refactoring is required as suggested by Gorkamorka.

Comment: Yup that's what I did and it's working :) ... Is this a more correct answer? or should I leave it at that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `ConnectionAndQuery` object is null.

I would check this for nullness upon construction, not when you try and use it. This will capture the error much earlier (and at a much more useful time). It's also possible (since error reporting isn't clear - see below) that this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Connecting to the database failed");
}
```

is capturing an error but leaving the statement object uninitialised (null). I would check nullness of the statement as a precondition or better still throw that originating exception such that the client code has to deal with a broken `ConnectionAndQuery` object.

This

```
System.out.println(e.getStackTrace().toString());
```

isn't very helpful, btw. I would rather do:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

since it'll dump the complete stack trace, and dump it to `stderr` (conventional destination for errors). At the moment you're calling `toString()` on the array of stack frames, and this doesn't really do anything useful.

Comment: Indeed it looks like the object is null even after is has been assigned at         this.caq = caq; in the constructor. But I use the same variable to later give a reference to the other class?

Comment: your `MainWindow` constructor is called before `connect()` i think right?

Comment: Well I don't think the statement or object can be null as they are used later, working perfectly fine. The printed stacktrace doesn't really give any clues I think excepet maybe this line: return statement.executeQuery(query); in the ConnectionAndQueries class. I also put this:   this.caq = caq;
  System.out.println(caq); in the constructor and I receive ConnectionAndQueries@103c0ad so it doesn't seem to be null?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I tried switching them around but there was no difference. Edit: Wait ! I think it works? other errors now but this once should have been solved :D Thanks

Comment: if the order was the issue please mark the response from @Gorkamorka as "the" answer. i had added my comment before seeing his, of course.